# Getting error for reading excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd

With using any mothods xlrd or openpyxl, I get error saying `KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"`

I checked whether that [Content_Types].xml really don't exist for my .xlsx by changing file format to .zip and open it, but clearly the .xml exists in there.

For now, I am using the alternative way by using win32com by get the file, load it, save it with new name and reload the data from the new file and delete the new file when jobs are done. The problem is, it takes way longer time than just directly read data from the original file and it often occurs errors when opening and closing the excel program.

Will there any other way to solve the issue I'm facing?

Comment: According to the error, the file name has a bracket in its name...

Comment: @po.pe I've just forgot to put it so it's not the main issue

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @Ludacia The names still don't match...

Comment: The content types manifest is required for any valid XLSX file.